# Is there a copy-on-write filesystem for Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, filesystems, fuse, macfuse

I'm on Snow Leopard. I have both MacFUSE and fuse4x installed. Is there a copy-on-write filesystem that I can install?

I tried building UnionFS-FUSE 0.25 using fuse4x's includes and libs, but I get this error:

```
error: ‘AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW’ undeclared
```

It seems that OS X doesn't define this constant (I grepped all of /usr/include and it wasn't found).

I also tried using OS X's built-in union mounts (`mount -o union`) but it didn't behave as expected. I mounted 2 filesystems (using dmg files) with the union option to the same mount point. The first was read-only, and had a directory called `d1` containing some files. The second did not have a directory with that name. When I tried to create a file in `d1` in the union mount, I got a read-only fs error. I expected it to automatically create the dir and the file under it, both in fs #2. I then tried to create `d1` in fs #2, but then the contents of `d1` in fs #1 were completely hidden (the dir appeared empty). Basically the union-ing behavior only happened at the root level of filesystems, and wasn't recursive.

If someone wants to try replicating the built-in union mount behavior, I used this [guide](http://aplawrence.com/foo-mac/union-mounts.html).

I'm not familiar with copy-on-write filesystems - does my expectation match how copy-on-write filesystems should work?

Comment: `mount -union` appears to be working as documented: *Causes the namespace at the mount point to appear as the union of the mounted filesystem root and the existing directory.  Lookups will be done in the mounted filesystem first.* That means when  finds `d1` in fs#1, that's used, instead of some virtual union directory being returned. So that's probably not a solution...

Comment: @DanielBeck thanks, I didn't notice that. But this means I'll need a different solution.

Answer (score 3):

After doing a little more research, I may have to give up on a pre-written solution and just write my own.

[PyFilesystem](http://code.google.com/p/pyfilesystem/) looks like it has potential, particularly the MultiFS fs type. Its FUSE code needs a [patch to work with fuse4x](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!topic/pyfilesystem-discussion/pF4-rkOrEJI).

The MultiFS documentation isn't clear what whether it will create a directory on the writable fs, but I'll give it a try.

**UPDATE**

The patch introduced a bug when it moved this line before the iconv CDLL loading:

```
_libfuse = CDLL(_libfuse_path)
```

Just move it right after and it should work on OS X. (A general fix requires also adding the line after the `if _system in` block.)

So I tried the MultiFS and it does **not** create missing directories on the writable FS. But I'm guessing it's easy to add (even though I'm not a python expert). Also, trying to overwrite or append to a file on one of the read-only FS's doesn't consistently create the corresponding path on the writable one. I get a lot of errors and hangs (the fuse process then starts using a lot of CPU). This solution still looks very promising though.